# MASM and Visual Studio C++ 2010 Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, masm

I'm having a bit of trouble with setting the whole thing up. I've followed a couple of tutorials, but they all lead me to the same error.

Here's what it always says, even if I don't have any code written down.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(49,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Debug\prog.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Taprog.asm" exited with code 1.
```

(This is with or without EP set, with either subsystem console or windows.)

I've also tried to run some assembly with the  MASM32Editor, but it always gives me the error

```
MASM : fatal error A1000: cannot open file : C:\masm32\Test.asm
```

Anyone know how to solve either of these, or maybe provide a working alternative?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong, look in the Output window for any messages produced by masm.

Comment: Oh, I fixed it by installing Visual Studio SP1. Thanks!